# Cannot recive jason data from url with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing basic code from tutorial for node.js it should take json data from file that is on url location:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. and save it in a new file that is created with the same code.
My code is below

```
const https=require('https');
const fs=require('fs');
const url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
https.get('url', res => {

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    let body='';

    res.on('data', data => {
       body += data;

    });
   res.on('end', ()=>{
  fs.writeFile('data.json', body, 'utf8', (err)=>{
      if(err) return err;
      consle.log('data was saved');
  });
   });
});

It give me this error
```

https.js:235
    throw new errors.Error('ERR_INVALID_DOMAIN_NAME');
    ^

```
Error [ERR_INVALID_DOMAIN_NAME]: Unable to determine the domain name
at request (https.js:235:13)
at Object.get (https.js:249:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Node\http-request.js:4:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
```

Can anyone tell me where i,m wrong

Comment: You are doing the request to `'url'`, just remove those quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
https.get(url, res => {
```

instead of

```
https.get('url', res => {
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I haven't notice.